# JQuery AjaxStart/Stop implement delay function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

While working on my single page app I was thinking about implementing a spinner and gray background. This would be great to prevent users of clicking multiple times on the buttons while process is loading and give them a signal that process is loading. However I looked over the web and there is JQuery `AjaxStart()` and `AjaxStop()` functions. So I used this to show the spinner on every ajax call in my app. Here is example of my code.
HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div id="loading-img"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('.overlay').delay(3500).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
 #loading-img {
        background: url(http://preloaders.net/preloaders/360/Velocity.gif) center center no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 20;
    }

    .overlay {
        background: #e9e9e9;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Code above works and spinner is showing with the gray background. Only problem with that was that spinner will show for half a second and I wanted to prevent that and put delay. So I have implemented `delay()` method to do the trick but nothing happened. My spinner should show only after 3 seconds. I'm not sure if something is wrong in my code. Also if this is the best method to implement spinner and gray background. If anyone have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: From https://api.jquery.com/delay:  `Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.`

Comment: You could trick it with a show animation of 1 millisecond.  `$('.overlay').delay(3500).show(1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this instead. Start a timer which can be cancelled in case loading finishes before the timeout has occurred

```
var timer;

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function() { $('.overlay').show(); }, 3500);

}).ajaxStop(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

In your code, the request might finish before the delay runs out. You'd try and hide the progress which wasn't shown then show the progress when the timeout completes.

Answer (score 1):

The `.delay()` method works on effects that can be queued.

> *Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the **no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide()** which do not use the effects queue.*
> -[jQuery .delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/#entry-longdesc)

Give `.show/hide()` a duration

### Demo

```js
$('.btn1').on('click', function() {
  $('#overlay1').delay(3500).fadeIn(750).delay(2000).fadeOut(750);
}); // this looks better

$('.btn2').on('click', function() {
  $('#overlay2').delay(3500).show(750).delay(2000).hide(750);
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay::after {
  content: url(https://loading.io/spinners/flat-ball/lg.flat-bouncing-circle-loading-icon.gif);
}
```

```html
<button class='btn1'>FadeIn/Out</button>
<button class='btn2'>Show/Hide</button>
<div id='overlay1' class='overlay'>FadeIn/Out</div>

<div id='overlay2' class='overlay'>Show/Hide</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```